# unable to modify source directory in debuild

Tags: debian, packaging

In my project, I use **CMake** and the source directory is not under the debian directory. I understand that I have to use the **--sourcedirectory** option in the **rules** to set the directory containing the file **CMakeLists.txt**.

But, whatever the path I set in this option, I have the same error `dh_auto_configure: error: invalid or non-existing path to the source directory: /path/to/cmake/dir/`. I have tried absolute and relative paths with no success.

The file rules is:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
BASH := /bin/bash

%:
    dh $@  --buildsystem=cmake --sourcedirectory=/path/to/cmake/dir/
    

override_dh_auto_configure:
    dh_auto_configure -- -DCMAKE_RULE_MESSAGES=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DTESTING=OFF
```

Comment: What tool are you using to run the build?

Comment: For the binary it is cmake with gcc. 
For the package, I run `debuild -us -uc -b`